# Simple function for enumerating bisections of $[0,1]$

Tags: rational-numbers, natural-numbers

Is there a simple function $f : \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ that returns further and further bisections of the segment $[0,1]$? For example, we could have $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=(1)$, $f(2)=1/2$, $f(3)=1/4, f(4)=3/4, f(5)=1/8,f(6)=3/8$, etc. The order can vary somewhat, but I would like it to work from top-down, so that lower $n$ gives fractions with the lower denominators.

I can think of a mechanical way to do this. Take the denominator as the largest power of 2 less than $n$. Then the numerator is the remainder, but we have to skip every reducible fraction that already came before. Is there a nice way to do this algebraically?

Comment: What is "bisection"? Do you want a function s.t. $f(n + 1) < f(n)$ for $n > 0$? There are a lot of such function, obvious example will be $f(0) = 0$ and $f(n) = \frac{1}{n}$ for $n > 0$.

Comment: @mihaild Sorry, I mean continually chopping the segments in half. So pick the end points, then divide and get 1/2. Then cut each half to get 1/4 and 3/4. Then again to get 1/8, 3/8, 5/8, and 7/8, and so on. So no, $f(n+1)<f(n)$ need not be met. And only powers of two will show up in the denominators this way

Comment: Your "etc" comes too early for a clear pattern to be defined. Please fix.

Comment: "skip every reducible fraction": if the denominators are powers of $2$, none of the fractions with an odd numerator are reducible.

Answer (score 1):

One answer: as commented [here](https://oeis.org/A006257), we can use the ratio of the sequences A006257/A062383.

So using those formulas we could get

$$f(n) = \frac{2(n - 2^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor}) + 1}{2^{\lceil\log_2(n+1)\rceil}}$$

For $n > 0$. The only thing we lose is that $1$ only comes at the end.